# Append string within first array element depending on key

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
address_types = ["main", "invoice", "work"]
```

I want to transform this array into:

```
[
  ["#{t('activerecord.attributes.address.address_type.main')}", "main"], 
  ["#{t('activerecord.attributes.address.address_type.invoice')}", "invoice"],
  ["#{t('activerecord.attributes.address.address_type.work')}", "work"]
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want those strings exactly? Or do you want the output of the `#{t...}` method in your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
address_types.map do |entry|
  [t("activerecord.attributes.address.address_type.#{entry}"), entry]
end
```